# wp_enqueue_style not loading CSS

Tags: wordpress

I am attempting to load a script using `wp_enqueue_style` following the advice on the Wordpres Codex, but the script doesn't seem to be included in the source. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
    function load_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

Comment: Is it the only asset thats not being loaded or no asset has been leaded at all?

Comment: Your script seems correct, so maybe you forget to **clear browsing data**.   
Depending on your browser cash policies, your browser may store your css file, and then completely ignore a standard page reload which wont display the change you just did.  
_To do so, on chrome browser, use the short key `ctrl` + `shift` + `delete`._

Answer (score 12):

Your action and function looks fine from here. The wp_enqueue_scripts hook should work perfectly for both stylesheets and scripts.

Have you tried echoing something out in the function to see if it's actually being called at all? I.e:

```
    function load_scripts() {
        echo "Does this output to the actual page?";
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

If it's not, you might have a problem with your placement of the code, but if you keep everything in functions.php and outside of any other scope this shouldn't be a problem.
Another thing that can cause this behaviour is if you have already registered a stylesheet or script with the same handle ("bootstrap.css" in this case). The first argument in the wp_enqueue_style() function is just a handle for internal dependency management and should be unique, try renaming it to something else and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 8):

1. Okay, first step is to ensure you are using the correct path of the CSS file.
   Add the following line in the functions.php of your theme or other appropriate place.

   ```
    print( get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
   ```

   This should print the URL of your desired stylesheet on top of the page. Copy and paste this URL in a new tab, if it opens a stylesheet then you are good to go. Otherwise, there is a mistake in the path.
2. Second step is to ensure that **wp_head()** is being called on the page you are displaying. It can be placed in your header template or top of archives/post files etc. This function actually renders the styles and scripts on the page.

   Without wp_head(), its basically useless to enque anything as you can add links and scripts manually if you know the exact paths.

Comment: wp_head is vital as you mentioned, but it will spam your <head> with all sorts of code you might not need, so see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214449/184180 how to get rid of it

Comment: That's pretty neat

Answer (score 4):

Note that in admin mode there is a special hook '[admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts)'. So, if there is need to load CSS in both modes, it should be done on two hooks.

```php
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');    
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to enqueue style on wp_enqueue_scripts  hook.
Try **wp_print_styles**.

```
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_scripts');
```

Also try to register style, first.

Comment: Do I have to register every style before I use the enqueue style?

Comment: I was following the information from here which doesn't mention anything about registering http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: Also, from the advice on the Codex page for 'wp_print_styles' it says "wp_print_styles should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts on the front page. Use wp_enqueue_scripts instead."

Comment: This is very incorrect. The wp_print_styles action is NOT meant for enqueueing styles or scripts. That's what the wp_enqueue_scripts action is for. Wordpress even throws a notice level error about this.

Answer (score 1):

in case you don't want to use `wp_head();` in your template, you could also include your styles directly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' ); ?>">
```

**beware** though: wp_head() includes tons of stuff (scripts, styles,...), by wordpress itself as well as most plugins, so only omit it if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Register the style first:

```
function register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style('my-plugin', plugins_url('my-plugin/css/plugin.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('my-plugin'); 
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

Do that way. Dont try to enqueue directly. And put code into functions.php of course.

Comment: It doesn't matters. You should put it as a suggestion but that's not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fist confirm path of the css file is correct or not if is it a correct try with below code :

```
  function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('load-custom-css-new', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

or Go with this URL.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Although I have implemented this many times before, I lost many hours to find out what went wrong with this.

Because I made my own themes, I had declared this file unit as “fuctions.php” (I lost the -n- letter).

So, besides all the things described above you should also consider, **take a good look at the file name and confirm that is “functions.php”** (not fuctions, not function etc).

This might be also the reason for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by hard refreshing the page with Ctrl + F5 to clear cache and the css loaded normally.

Comment: Yes, In my case, I had a plugin - W3 Total Cache, when I deactivated it, css loaded,

Answer (score 0):

If you are protecting the directory with .htpasswd, the https call generated by get_stylesheet... will fail, and you might lose some time chasing that one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I might get the 'Golden Shovel' badge for digging, but I had the same issue today.
For custom themes, it's also worth remembering to include `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in your files

Answer (score 0):

in your header.php file check if you have used `wp_head()`
i had the same problem and by adding the `wp_head()` my problem was solved